# React navigation header resizes on navigating to a screen with react-navigation/native-stack

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I'm getting a strange behavior when navigating into a screen containing the code below.

<strike>I believe it has something to do with how the flex containers are rendered when navigating into a new screen, but I'm not sure.</strike>

This seems to happen when creating navigation stacks with '@react-navigation/native-stack', and once for the entire navigation regardless. See EDIT 2 below for more details.

```js
export const AccountScreen = ({ route, navigation }: any) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Top</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{}}>
        <Text>Bottom</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I created a snack to demonstrate: https://snack.expo.dev/@kickbk/navigation

The issue is that when I navigate to `Account`, you may notice that `Bottom` sort of jumps up the first time it renders the screen. It's very brief, but it happens.

This glitch becomes more visible when adding content such as images instead of Text.
On a very bad Android phone it sometimes gets stuck where the `Bottom` part gets hidden below and behind the navigation bar.

If you look at this snack and go to Carousel.tsx, you will see the content I load into `Screens > AccountScreen`.

How do I do this correctly? How do I load this screen so the content will not jitter like that?

**MORE INFO**

I screen recorded what I was seeing and you can clearly see it jmuping around, frame by frame:

Frame 1

[image: Frame 1]

Frame 2

[image: Frame 2]

Frame 3

[image: Frame 3]

Frame 4

[image: Frame 4]

**EDIT 2**

It looks like this header adjusting height behavior happens with `@react-navigation/native-stack`. When switching to importing stack from `@react-navigation/stack`, and then navigating to `Account`, the glitch doesn't happen.

However, when launching the app, despite all the stack getting imported from `@react-navigation/stack`, the header gets adjusted once. I am guessing it's because the entire JS implementation of stacks sits inside a native component which cuases this behavior when loaded once. Maybe caused by `NavigationContainer` from `'@react-navigation/native';`?

I have updated the snack (https://snack.expo.dev/@kickbk/navigation) with a minimal implementation so there's no doubt on possible third party dependency influencing this.

Comment: Your bottom container doesn't have a set height, and the top container expands, so there might be some back and forth. Does it go away if you set the height of either container? You could also try justifyContent: space-between if you're looking for a footer type thing.

Comment: It's very strange. I tried justifyContent: space-between, flexBasis, grow and shrink. I tried adding height. It's still jumping. It's very easy to see when you screen record on Android and then go frame by frame.

Comment: It looks like this may be caused by `@react-navigation/native-stack`. When generating stacks with `@react-navigation/stack`, the header on expands on init once (which is bad), but not when navigating into another screen.